R what is the best glmmTMB model family to fit positively skewed index data
I am attempting to create a linear mixed effects model (lmer) with an positively skewed index dataset (1-4) that results in the best fit (distribution pictured below code).
Database
cover_code_data <- structure(list(Year = c(18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Low", 
"High"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), `Module #` = c(215, 
212, 212, 212, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 212, 215, 214, 
215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 214, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 
216, 216, 214, 214, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 216, 216, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 216, 216, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 
212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 212, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 215, 215, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 
216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 
216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 
216, 216, 216, 213, 213, 213, 213, 213, 214, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 216, 216, 216, 212, 212, 212, 
212, 212, 212, 213, 213, 213, 213, 214, 214, 214, 214, 214, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 216, 212, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 216, 
216, 216, 213, 213, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 
215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 213, 215, 214, 213, 213, 213, 213, 
213, 213, 213, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 
112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 112, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 114, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 
115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 116, 
116, 114, 114, 114, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 115, 114, 114, 114, 
114, 114, 114, 113, 113, 113, 112, 116, 116, 114, 114, 113, 113, 
113, 113, 112, 112, 112, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111), cover_code = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1), Season = c("fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", 
"summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "summer", "fall", "summer", "fall", "summer"), cover_code_trans = c(1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1.4142135623731, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1.4142135623731, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.4142135623731, 
1.31607401295249, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1.4142135623731, 
1, 1.31607401295249, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1.4142135623731, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.4142135623731, 
1.18920711500272, 1.31607401295249, 1.18920711500272, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 
1.18920711500272, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1.4142135623731, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 
1.4142135623731, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1.31607401295249, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1.18920711500272, 1.31607401295249, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1.4142135623731, 
1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.31607401295249, 
1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1, 
1.31607401295249, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 
1.4142135623731, 1.18920711500272, 1.4142135623731, 1.31607401295249, 
1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1, 1.18920711500272, 
1, 1.18920711500272, 1, 1.4142135623731, 1.4142135623731, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-758L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


I am having difficulty with getting a better model fit and am looking for guidance as to the best family or distribution to use in the glmmTMB function to get the best model fit.  I attempted to use a gamma distribution because of the heavy positive skew in the response variable.
However, this did not result in the best fit.  I am looking for the best family to use or model to create to fit the data best.  I am also open to other modeling ideas if glmmTMB does not seem appropriate or as effective.  Any insight would be appreciated and thank you in advance.
Analysis and fit
plotNormalHistogram(cover_code_data$cover_code)

module_algae_TS5_6 <- cover_code_data$`Module #`
module_algae_TS5_6 <-  as.factor(cover_code_data$ID)

cover_code_lmer_TS5_6 <- glmmTMB(cover_code ~ 
    Site_long*Shelter + (1|module_algae_TS5_6) + 
    (1|module_algae_TS5_6), 
    data = cover_code_data_timestep_5_6, 
    na.action = "na.fail")
summary(cover_code_lmer_TS5_6)

DHARMa::testDispersion(cover_code_lmer_TS5_6)
simulationOutput <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(fittedModel = 
    cover_code_lmer_TS5_6, plot = TRUE)

# fit
qqnorm(resid(cover_code_lmer_TS5_6))
qqline(resid(cover_code_lmer_TS5_6))





It looks like your data are ordinal. I would start with the ordinal package (for frequentist fitting) or brms or MCMCglmm (for Bayesian fitting).
